# Remove product from Store in Array with Reducer removing wrong item

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, reduce

So I am using a Store to persist the state of props in my react front end.
However, in the cart I would like to allow the user to remove an item if they would like and next give them the ability to update QTY, etc. All from the cart and not from the initial page used to "Add to cart".

I have tried a couple methods and they seemed to work but once more items are in the Array it doesnt seem to be working as intended but once the user logs out and back in of course the DB is persisting it correctly.

My "Remove_Product" reducer looks like this:

```
 case REMOVE_PRODUCT:
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-case-declarations
        const rmindex = action.payload.product_index
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-case-declarations
        let newProduct = [...state.product]
        newProduct.splice(rmindex, 1)
        return {
            ...state,
           product: newProduct,
           loading: true
        }
```

This works until there are more items and I would like to find the best practice method for handling this so I can continue to use best practices in the application as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean "This works until there are more items" but,

I personally prefer `filter` when removing an item from array state, which can directly return a new array with less code (no mutation of state :D)

```
case REMOVE_PRODUCT:
  const { product_index } = action.payload;
  return {
    ...state,
    product: state.product.filter((item, index) => product_index !== index),
    loading: true
  }
```

Comment: Even less code if you remove your const declaration - it’s just creating an alias

Comment: @Adam you're right, changed to destruction instead, for better read